# httpOnlyCookies, does it only affect cookies created on the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies

If I set `httpOnlyCookies="true"` in web.config, that should affect all cookies created server side right?

But does it somehow affect cookies set by jquery plugins in the gui, or do they stay unaffected on the next page response?

I'm guessing they would stay unaffected, but I would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guessing is right.
Option httpOnlyCookies="true" means that all cookies which are created by Asp.Net will be HttpOnly. It does not affect cookies created on client side.